# Canvas implementation of Circle Packing is jittery when zooming

Tags: javascript, canvas, d3.js

I'm trying to learn canvas (to improve a visualization I made a few weeks ago in D3.js which is very slow due to many DOM elements: http://nbremer.github.io/occupations/). I managed to make a canvas based circle packing in which you can zoom, but it's rather jittery while zooming: http://bl.ocks.org/nbremer/667e4df76848e72f250b

Does anybody have any suggestions on how I can improve this? I tried d3.timer and am now using requestAnimationFrame, but that doesn't seem to make a difference. (Once I manage to get this working, I still want to add the small bar charts that are packed in each white circle as in the original example)

Thank you!

Comment: btw, both of them work smoothly on my iMac. What hardware configurations do you target?

Comment: I'm working on Windows 10, but I also want it to work on mobile and there it takes a very long time for the visual to initialize and next zoom into the touched node. But the jitter I see even on my windows 10 laptop, especially if you zoom in on a very small circle

Comment: Jitter?? do you mean slow frame rate. If so this is due to the device hardware not being up to the job. You should also check your browser to make sure it is using the graphics hardware to render.

Comment: **Feedback: as with kmandov, the animation is not jittery on my Win10 / 2.16Gz desktop.** But given the large display required for your visualization, you will likely have to refactor the design for mobile -- maybe drill-down instead of showing all circles at once. If you refactor, then your SVG element count will be naturally smaller and might not be jittery.

Comment: It should actually be responsive, so scaled down for mobile. Also this example uses canvas to draw the graph so there are no SVG elements in the HTML. Eventually I found the solution [here](http://bl.ocks.org/smoli/d7e4f9199c15d71258b5) which I adjusted to [this](http://bl.ocks.org/nbremer/db24422abdb20150a9dd). It appears that the jitter disappeared even on my laptop when I added the canvas circles based on the data itself instead of the dummy d3 nodes (but that did require a custom interpolator for the zoom)